# Unable to modify TFS Preview's Work Item Templates

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I modified a TFS Preview's WIT file, and while saving I'm getting "TF237113: You don't have enough permissions to complete the import operation." error.

Comment: By TFS preview do you mean visual studio online? As in xxxx.visualstudio.com ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom work item types are not supported on TF Service (formerly tfspreview, also known as Visual Studio Online).

See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/075c464e-5870-48cc-a1dc-af863344c51f/create-custom-work-item-field